# MySQL CLI asks for password but doesn't use it

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database for replication.

The database is on a machine that's part of a secured network, so after opening the security enough to allow my replication destination access to the 3306 port I wanted to connect through the CLI tool to check the connection.

However, no matter how I try to connect, I get the following response:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '{user}'@'{IP}' (using password: NO)`

Despite what this message says, the user that I've been trying to connect with does have a password set and I do provide it for the CLI.

I've tried passing the password interactively, inline, and through a .cnf file

I've made sure the password is correct, and made sure that the user is expected to come from the destination IP.

I've changed the permissions for the user to ALL in case there was a permission that was denying access.

I've made sure that the destination server does not have any users that can log in with a password in case that was affecting default behavior.

None of those have changed the behavior, and unfortunately the only resources I can find online are how to log in if one has forgotten to root password, or how to set the root password after one done a fresh install.

EDIT: These are the commands I've used to try to pass the password to the CLI:

```
Interactively:

mysql --host={destination IP} --protocol=tcp -u remote_user -p

Inline:

mysql --host={destination IP} --protocol=tcp -u remote_user -p {password}

Configuration file:

(Config file {user}@{host}.cnf)
[client]
host="{host}"
user="{user}"
password="{password}"
protocol="tcp"

(Command)
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/{user}@{host}.cnf
```

Comment: Please show how you supplied the password. Because you're obviously not doing it correctly.